# How can i use single qoutes in html using python

Tags: python, html, shortcode

Here is the code title its an attribute

````
``` src="[sc name='testt2' id='''+title+'''][/sc]/```
````

whene i put it between single qoutes the attribute shows up like a html code :

````
``` src="[sc name='testt2' id=''''+title+''''][/sc]/```
````

Comment: Escape the (') with \.

Comment: or use `.format`, or better yet, an f-string

Comment: html? I am struggling to figure out the problem here. Is it that you end up with `+title+` in the resulting string? In that second case you have three string literals `''' src="[sc name='testt2' id='''` then `'+title+'` then `'''][/sc]/'''`. If that's not what you want, and the first example works for you... then don't do that second thing!

Comment: Are you trying to write an HTML attribute? If so, include the exact string you want as output. And write this as a working script (I think just initializing `title` would do).

Comment: If I understand the question, an f-string seems like the best choice: `f''' src="[sc name='testt2' id='{title}'][/sc]/'''`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add \ backslash before each comma.

Comment: Comma? Did you mean single quotes? And which ones? I think an example would be good here.